What is the theory of computably saturated models of ZFC with an *externally well-founded* predicate?
For any model of $M$ of ZFC, we can extend it to a model $M_{ew}$ with an "externally well-founded" predicate $ew$. For $x \in M$, We say that $M_{ew} \vDash ew(x)$ when there is no infinite sequence $y_n \in M$ such that $\dots \in_M y_2 \in_M y_1 \in_M y_0 \in_M x$.
My question is how to axiomatize the following theory:
$$T = \{\phi : \forall M. \text{$M$ is a computably saturated model of ZFC implies $M_{ew} \vDash \phi$} \}$$
Every theorem of $T$ without the $ew$ predicate is true in every computably saturated model of ZFC, and therefore in every model of ZFC (since every model is elementarily equivalent to a computably saturated one). Thus by Gödel's completeness theorem, the theorem is true in ZFC, and thus $T$ is conservative over ZFC.
However, $T$ is more the same as ZFC. For example, "there is a natural number greater than every externally well-founded natural number" is a theorem.
(Note ironically that there are models of $T$ with elements that satisfy $\text{ew}$ but aren't actually externally well-founded, of course.)
To make the question more precise, here's what would constitute an "acceptable" axiomatization. It should consist of a finite number of "axiom schema", where each axiom schema is generated from a formula with class variables. Axioms are generated by replacing the class variables with definable classes and then taking the universal closure. Each class variable may have restrictions on what symbols are allowed in the definition of the class that get substituted for them. (ZFC is acceptably axiomatized in this sense.)

$ew(x)$ iff $x$ is in $V_n$ for some standard $n\in\omega$, right? So the theory is definitionally equivalent to the, perhaps simpler, theory where you add a predicate for standard natural numbers instead of ew.

@EmilJeřábek ah yes, that does sound correct!

I only now read the last paragraph. The theory is certainly not axiomatizable by finitely many schemata, as it is not recursively axiomatizable: it includes true arithmetic (interpreted by restriction of the usual operations on $\omega$ to the new predicate).

If you changed it to saturated, instead of just computably saturated, the theory would interpret second-order arithmetic, since every set of natural numbers would be in the standard system.

Emil, perhaps you might post an answer, since that observation shows that there can be no easy characterization of this theory. Can we show that the theory exceeds $0^{(\omega)}$ in complexity? Or perhaps equivalent.

@JoelDavidHamkins The theory is $\Pi^1_1$-complete in terms of complexity. But there still might be some nontrivial characterization. In particular, if I drop the recursive saturation requirement, the theory (with a predicate for $\mathbb N$ rather than ew) is axiomatized by ZFC, the axioms $\mathbb N(n)$ for each standard $n$, and the $\omega$-rule $\phi(0),\phi(1),\phi(2),\dots\mathrel/\forall x,(\mathbb N(x)\to\phi(x))$. But I'm not sure how to make it work with recursive saturation. Though saturation for recursive types of bounded complexity follows from just $\mathbb N\subsetneq\omega$.

@JoelDavidHamkins In any case, if the observation "the theory is not recursive axiomatizable as it includes true arithmetic" were the whole answer, this would not be a research-level question, and the appropriate course of action would be to vote to close it, not to post an answer.

@EmilJeřábek Since countable computably saturated models $M$ of ZF are precisely those countable models of ZF that are (1) $\omega$-nonstandard and (2) have an expansion to a satisfaction class $S$ such that $(M,S)$ satisfies Tarski's clauses for each standard formula, and (M,S) satisfies replacement in the extended language, it appears that the theory asked about can be obtained as the set-theoretical consequences of the modification of the theory you formulated (using the $\omega$-rule), by changing ZFC to ZFC + S is a satisfaction class (as a scheme).

@AliEnayat Ah, you are right, that works. Do you think the expansion is necessary to get a decent characterization? I was hoping that it could be described in the original language by some kind of generalized $\omega$-rules, possibly extracted from an $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$ proof, but perhaps that is not workable.

@EmilJeřábek Well, some people on MO have such high standards that they seem to think every question that can be answered should therefore be closed for that reason. But I think the site is more worthwhile when interesting questions get answered. (I wasn't suggesting that quoted sentence as the "whole" answer.) For example, I didn't notice the $\Pi^1_1$-completeness, but if you had posted an answer to that effect, I would have learned something interesting. In any case, I'm more interested in the complexity issue than in providing a proof-theoretic account.

@JoelDavidHamkins I am not sure who first noticed the $\Pi^1_1$-completeness in this context, but it even came up in the last section of our paper "ZFC does proves that Ord is not weakly compact", in part (b) of the last remark of the paper.

@JoelDavidHamkins It makes no sense to demand that an answer be posted while the right answer is still in the process of being figured out. It is very detrimental to the quality of the site to post half-baked unfinished answers just so that the question can be quickly ticked off as "answered". Surely you are not in such a hurry that you need to read the answer just now?

@EmilJeřábek That's fine, and I'm not in any hurry (but this is now a different argument you are making). When I made my suggestion, I was thinking of those observations as constituting a satisfactory resolution of the question. You evidently want a fuller account, which of course is fine.  My suggestion is an attempt to push back against an unfortunate practice on MO by which questions get answered in the comments and that's that, which I think doesn't work as well as posting actual answers.

@EmilJeřábek About your idea of not expanding the language and working with an infinitary logic: recursive saturation is expressible in $L_{\omega_1, \omega}$, a logic that has a completeness theorem, wouldn't that do it?

@ChristopherKing Could you please a sentence or two to your question to clarify what led you to pose the question?

@AliEnayat That's my starting point: both recursive saturation and standardness of $\mathbb N$ are expressible in $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$, and therefore validity in $T$ can be witnessed by a suitable $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$ proof. But this is not a proof in the language of $T$, as it will involve infinitary formulas. The problem is whether the infinitary formulas can be eliminated, in the way it is possible with the $\omega$-rule.

@EmilJeřábek Thanks for the clarification. By the way, another way to expand is to add a unary predicate $U(x)$ to the language of set theory and (1) add the sentence that says that $U$ is an unbounded subset of ordinals, and (2) add the collection of  sentences of the form : if $\alpha$ is in $U$, then $V_{\alpha}$ is $\Sigma_n$-elementary in $V$ (as $n$ ranges in $\omega$).  This will do the job since a model of ZF is recursively saturated iff it is expandable to this theory (as opposed to the previous expansion which only worked for ctble models, this one works for all).

I do admit the answer should've been obvious (of course it interprets true arithmetic!), sorry 'bout that! I wouldn't be offended if closure is warranted. An answer that characterizes the theory would be great tho!

@AliEnayat I suppose by main curiosity is how this theory compares to IST. Although they are based on a similar idea, it appears they are in fact quite different (like not being recursively axiomatizable, lol).

I’ll give up on the $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$ idea for the moment, as I can’t get it to work.

Observe that if $M\models\def\zfc{\mathrm{ZFC}}\zfc$ has nonstandard $\omega$, then $x\in M$ is externally well founded iff its rank $\rho(x)$ is a standard natural number: this follows easily by iterating the observation that if $\rho(x)=\sup\{\rho(y)+1:y\in x\}$ is infinite or nonstandard, then $\rho(y)$ is infinite or nonstandard for some $y\in x$ as well. Thus, $T$ is definitionally equivalent with a similarly defined theory where we have a predicate $\def\N{\mathbb N}\N(x)$ for standard natural numbers in place of ew. I will henceforth assume $T$ is formulated in this way.
Assuming ZFC is consistent, the theory $T$ cannot be axiomatized by finitely many schemata, as it is not recursively axiomatizable. In fact, it is $\Pi^1_1$-complete. On the one hand, given a $\Pi^1_1$ sentence of the form $\forall X\,\phi(X)$ where $\phi$ is arithmetical, we have
$$\N\models\forall X\,\phi(X)\iff T\vdash\forall X\subseteq\omega\,\phi^\N(X),$$
where $\phi^\mathbb N$ denotes the relativization of all quantifiers in $\phi$ to the $\N$ predicate (in particular, this means that the formula can only query $x\in X$ for $x\in\N$, thus the quantifier over $X\subseteq\omega$ really quantifies over subsets of $\N$ coded in the model). For the left-to-right implication, if $M$ is any model of ZFC, and $X\in M$, then $M\models\phi^\N(X)$ iff $\N\models\phi(X\cap\N)$ (identifying standard natural numbers with the corresponding elements of $M$); thus, if $\N\models\forall X\,\phi(X)$, then also $M\models\forall X\subseteq\omega\,\phi^\N(X)$. For right-to-left, if $\N\not\models\phi(X)$ for some $X\subseteq\N$, then using compactness and the consistency of ZFC, there is a recursively saturated $M\models\zfc$ that contains an $X'$ such that $X'\cap\N=X$, thus $M\models T\land\neg\phi^\N(X')$.
On the other hand, $T$ is complete wrt models $(M,\N)$ where $M$ is a countable recursively saturated model of ZFC. Such a model $M$ and its satisfaction predicate can be encoded by a subset $S\subseteq\N$, and it is easy to see that the property “$S$ is a satisfaction predicate of a recursively saturated model $M$ of ZFC that $(M,\N)\models\phi$” is arithmetical. Thus, $T$ is $\Pi^1_1$.
Nevertheless we can describe $T$ in some nontrivial ways. First, by the usual completeness theorem for $\omega$-logic, the theory of models $(M,\N)$ where $M\models\zfc$ can be axiomatized by $\let\ob\overline\zfc+\{\N(\ob n):n\in\N\}+{}$the $\omega$-rule
$$\dfrac{\phi(\ob0),\phi(\ob1),\phi(\ob2),\dots}{\forall x\,(\N(x)\to\phi(x))},$$
where $\ob n$ denotes the numeral for $n$ (the usual definition of $n$ in the language of ZFC).
In order to generalize this to $T$, we can use the idea from a comment by Ali Enayat: let $\zfc^U$ denote the extension of $\zfc$ in a language with a new predicate $U(x)$, and axioms ensuring that $U$ is an unbounded class of ordinals $\alpha$ such that $(V_\alpha,{\in})$ is an elementary substructure of the universe w.r.t. all standard formulas. (The replacement schema is not extended to the new language.) Then $M\models\zfc$ is recursively saturated iff it has nonstandard $\omega$ and it expands to a model of $\zfc^U$: on the one hand, for any ordinal $\beta\in M$, the existence of $\alpha>\beta$ such that $V_\alpha^M\prec M$ follows from recursive saturation, hence we can take for $U$ the set of all such $\alpha$. On the other hand, a recursive type can be coded in a model with nonstandard $\omega$ by some $p\in M$, $p\subseteq\omega$ using overspill; if $\alpha\in U$ is such that all parameters of the type belong to $V_\alpha$, the type is finitely satisfiable in $V_\alpha$, hence using overspill again, a nonstandardly finite part of $p$ is satisfiable, hence the original type is satisfied in $V_\alpha$, and a fortiori in $V$.
Then $T$ consists of all $U$-free sentences provable in $\zfc^U+\{\N(\ob n):n\in\N\}+\exists x\in\omega\,\neg\N(x)+{}$the $\omega$-rule.

"let $\def\zfc{\mathrm{ZFC}}\zfc^U$ denote the extension of $\zfc$ in a language with a new predicate $U(x)$, and axioms ensuring that $\omega$ is nonstandard" Does $\zfc^U$'s language also include the $\mathbb N(n)$ predicate? If not, what are the axioms ensuring $\omega$ is nonstandard?

No, it does not yet include $\mathbb N$. But you are right, I can’t do that. I’ll fix it.

Hmm, doesn't the characterization using the $\omega$-rule imply that the theory's complexity is $\Sigma_1^1$ (and thus can't be $\Pi_1^1$-complete)? $\phi$ is a theorem of $T$ with the $\omega$-rule iff there exists a well-ordered countable set and a set of sentences indexed by that set such that each sentence is an axiom of $T$ or follows from previous sentences by the rules of inference and such that $\phi$ is one of those sentences.

You have hidden an extra universal SO quantifier in “well-ordered”, thus your description is only $\Sigma^1_2$, not $\Sigma^1_1$. You can make it $\Pi^1_1$ if you express it as “$\phi$ belongs to every deductively closed set of formulas closed under the $\omega$-rule”.

A tiny comment: in the theory $T$, we don't need to insist that the replacement scheme is extended (in contrast to the the sibling theory that has a satisfaction predicate) since by using the ZF reflection theorem plus recursive saturation one can bypass the appeal to resplendence to get an expansion to $T$ in the absence of replacement in the extended language (and indeed there is no need for countablity either).  I learned this argument from the following 1980 paper of John Schlipf:
https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1980-080-01/S0002-9939-1980-0574523-6/

@Ali I need (or at least I think so)  replacement, or really just separation, to prove the other direction: that the $\in$-reduct of a model of ZFC$^U$ is recursively saturated. Specifically, I'm using overspill for a formula that involves the satisfaction predicate constructed from $U$. Without separation for the extended language, I don't see why the formula couldn't define the cut of standard numbers. Or am I missing something?

@EmilJeřábek You can bypass the overspill argument (and therefore separation) by taking advantage of the fact that structures that live in $\omega$-nonstandard models of ZF are recursively saturated.  So, to prove recursive saturation of the model $M$, given a finitely realizable type $p(x)$, we go to a high enough $\alpha \in U$ that contains the parameters of $p(x)$ and argue that since $V^{M}{\alpha}$ is recursively saturated, $V^{M}{\alpha}$ realizes $p(x)$, and since $V^{M}_{\alpha}$and is an elementary submodel of $M$, $M$ realizes $p(x)$.

@AliEnayat Ah, I see! Thank you for patiently explaining the argument.
